# Convert floats to ints in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, integer

I've been working with data imported from a CSV. Pandas changed some columns to float, so now the numbers in these columns get displayed as floating points! However, I need them to be displayed as integers or without comma. Is there a way to convert them to integers or not display the comma?

Comment: You can change the type (so long as there are no missing values) `df.col = df.col.astype(int)`

Comment: This question is two questions at the same time, and the title of this question reflects only one of them.

Comment: For an people hitting the above and finding it useful in concept but not working for you, this is the version that worked for me in python 3.7.5 with pandas X: `df = df.astype(int)`

Answer (score 299, accepted):

To modify the float output do this:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(range(5), columns=['a'])
df.a = df.a.astype(float)
df

Out[33]:

          a
0 0.0000000
1 1.0000000
2 2.0000000
3 3.0000000
4 4.0000000

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
df

Out[35]:

   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

Comment: In the latest version of pandas you need to add copy = False to the arguments of astype to avoid a warning

Comment: Is it needed to do `df.a = df.a.astype(float)` ? Does this make a copy (not sure how the `copy` param to [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) is used) ? Anyway to update the type "in place" ?

Comment: @EdChum, is there a way to prevent Pandas from converting types to begin with? For example try `DF.({'200': {'#': 354, '%': 0.9971830985915493},
 '302': {'#': 1, '%': 0.0028169014084507044}})`  Note the # get converted to float and they are rows, not columns. because each is a `Series` which can only store a single uniform type?

Comment: @alancalvitti what is your intention here to preserve the values or the `dtype`? If it's `dtype` then you need to create those columns as `dtype` `object` so it allows mixed, otherwise my advice would be to just use float and when doing comparisons use `np.isclose`

Comment: @EdChum, the intention is to preserve the input types. So the `#` above should remain ints, while the `%` are typically floats.

Comment: @alancalvitti You'd need to define the dtypes as `object` to allowed mixed dtypes, however, if you perform a arithmetic operation the dtype may not be preserved

Comment: @EdChum, is that an option for DataFrame?  Are you saying even after defining dtypes as `objects` that if I say multiplied `%` values by 100.0 that that would affect the independent `#` component?

Comment: Possibly it's very complicated as it is down to what findings you call and what the target is. I wouldn't think this works 100% of the time

Comment: I think it is useful to add that if you do this, all floats will be changed. To reset this, use `pd.reset_option('display.float_format')`

Answer (score 283):

Use the [`pandas.DataFrame.astype(<type>)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) function to manipulate column dtypes.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,4), columns=list("ABCD"))
>>> df
          A         B         C         D
0  0.542447  0.949988  0.669239  0.879887
1  0.068542  0.757775  0.891903  0.384542
2  0.021274  0.587504  0.180426  0.574300
>>> df[list("ABCD")] = df[list("ABCD")].astype(int)
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
```

EDIT:

To handle missing values:

```
>>> df
          A         B     C         D
0  0.475103  0.355453  0.66  0.869336
1  0.260395  0.200287   NaN  0.617024
2  0.517692  0.735613  0.18  0.657106
>>> df[list("ABCD")] = df[list("ABCD")].fillna(0.0).astype(int)
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: I tried your approach and it gives me a ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer

Comment: @MJP You cannot convert series from float to integer if there are missing values see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na, you have to use floats

Comment: The values aren't missing, but the column doesn't specify a value for each row on purpose. Is there any way to achieve a workaround? Since those values are foreign key ids, I need ints.

Comment: I've made an edit in which all NaN's are replaced with a 0.0.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "The values aren't missing, but the column doesn't specify a value for each row on purpose". Is this like a pivot table, where the values below the value are empty but implictly the same as the one above? You may have to use a .ffill() on your FK columns to fill it before converting types.

Comment: I am modifying a csv so I can import it as a table to a database. This column is a column of foreign keys from another table b, not all rows have a relation to that table.

Comment: If you can have a NaN in the FK column, then could you replace the NaN's with some other random number, let's say if all current FK's are positive integers, then use a negative int like -999 to distinguish empty values. Another option is to only include the rows that have a value: "df[df['FK_COL'].notnull()]".  Then apply the filling on NaN values, and save this dataframe to a new variable for loading into the database.

Comment: Or better yet, if you are only modifying a CSV, then: df.to_csv("path.csv",na_rep="",float_format="%.0f",index=False)  But this will edit all the floats, so it may be better to convert your FK column to a string, do the manipulation, and then save.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this one df.to_csv("path.csv",na_rep="",float_format="%.0f",index=False) , and it worked for me (this column only contains "integers")

Comment: To solve the problem of **ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer ** you can use `df.fillna(0)`

Answer (score 66):

Considering the following data frame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.rand(3, 4), columns=list("ABCD"))
>>> print(df)
...           A         B         C         D
... 0  8.362940  0.354027  1.916283  6.226750
... 1  1.988232  9.003545  9.277504  8.522808
... 2  1.141432  4.935593  2.700118  7.739108
```

Using a list of column names, change the type for multiple columns with `applymap()`:

```
>>> cols = ['A', 'B']
>>> df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(np.int64)
>>> print(df)
...    A  B         C         D
... 0  8  0  1.916283  6.226750
... 1  1  9  9.277504  8.522808
... 2  1  4  2.700118  7.739108
```

Or for a single column with `apply()`:

```
>>> df['C'] = df['C'].apply(np.int64)
>>> print(df)
...    A  B  C         D
... 0  8  0  1  6.226750
... 1  1  9  9  8.522808
... 2  1  4  2  7.739108
```

Comment: What if there is a NaN in the value?

Comment: @Zhang18 I tried this solution and in case of NaN you have this error: `ValueError: ('cannot convert float NaN to integer', u'occurred at index <column_name>')`

Comment: @enri: Can try the following code - `df['C'] = df['C'].dropna().apply(np.int64)`

Answer (score 29):

### To convert all float columns to int

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 4) * 10, columns=list('PQRS'))
>>> print(df)
...     P           Q           R           S
... 0   4.395994    0.844292    8.543430    1.933934
... 1   0.311974    9.519054    6.171577    3.859993
... 2   2.056797    0.836150    5.270513    3.224497
... 3   3.919300    8.562298    6.852941    1.415992
... 4   9.958550    9.013425    8.703142    3.588733

>>> float_col = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']) # This will select float columns only
>>> # list(float_col.columns.values)

>>> for col in float_col.columns.values:
...     df[col] = df[col].astype('int64')

>>> print(df)
...     P   Q   R   S
... 0   4   0   8   1
... 1   0   9   6   3
... 2   2   0   5   3
... 3   3   8   6   1
... 4   9   9   8   3
```

Answer (score 29):

### Use `'Int64'` for NaN support

- `astype(int)` and `astype('int64')` **cannot** handle missing values *(numpy int)*
- `astype('Int64')` (note the capital `I`) [**can** handle missing values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) *(pandas int)*

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('Int64') # capital I
```

This assumes you want to keep missing values as NaN. If you plan to impute them, you could `fillna` first [as Ryan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21291383/13138364).

---

### Examples of `'Int64'` (capital `I`)

1. If the floats are already rounded, just use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [99.0, np.nan, 42.0]})

   df['A'] = df['A'].astype('Int64')
   #       A
   # 0    99
   # 1  <NA>
   # 2    42
   ```
2. If the floats are **not** rounded yet, [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html) before [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3.14159, np.nan, 1.61803]})

   df['A'] = df['A'].round().astype('Int64')
   #       A
   # 0     3
   # 1  <NA>
   # 2     2
   ```
3. To read int+NaN data from a file, use `dtype='Int64'` to avoid the need for converting at all:

   ```
   csv = io.StringIO('''
   id,rating
   foo,5
   bar,
   baz,2
   ''')

   df = pd.read_csv(csv, dtype={'rating': 'Int64'})
   #     id  rating
   # 0  foo       5
   # 1  bar    <NA>
   # 2  baz       2
   ```

---

### Notes

- `'Int64'` is an alias for [`Int64Dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html):

  ```
  df['A'] = df['A'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype()) # same as astype('Int64')
  ```
- Sized/signed aliases are available:

  |  | lower bound | upper bound |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | **`'Int8'`** | -128 | 127 |
  | **`'Int16'`** | -32,768 | 32,767 |
  | **`'Int32'`** | -2,147,483,648 | 2,147,483,647 |
  | **`'Int64'`** | -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 | 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 |
  | **`'UInt8'`** | 0 | 255 |
  | **`'UInt16'`** | 0 | 65,535 |
  | **`'UInt32'`** | 0 | 4,294,967,295 |
  | **`'UInt64'`** | 0 | 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 |

Answer (score 22):

This is a quick solution in case you want to convert more columns of your `pandas.DataFrame` from float to integer considering also the case that you can have NaN values.

```
cols = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']
for col in cols:
   df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x == x else "")
```

I tried with `else x)` and `else None)`, but the result is still having the float number, so I used `else ""`.

Comment: it will apply the `""` to all the values in `col`

Comment: It will apply empty string ("") to all the missing values, if that is what is required, but the rest of the values will be integer.

Comment: Thanks for this. This worked when .astype() and .apply(np.int64) did not.

Comment: This feels hacky, and I see no reason to use it over the many alternatives available.

Comment: Thanks, this was the only answer that properly handled NaN and preserves them (as empty string or 'N/A') while converting other values to int.

Answer (score 16):

Expanding on @Ryan G mentioned usage of the `pandas.DataFrame.astype(<type>)` method, one can use the `errors=ignore` argument to only convert those columns that do not produce an error, which notably simplifies the syntax. Obviously, caution should be applied when ignoring errors, but for this task it comes very handy.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
>>> df *= 10
>>> print(df)
...           A       B       C       D
... 0   2.16861 8.34139 1.83434 6.91706
... 1   5.85938 9.71712 5.53371 4.26542
... 2   0.50112 4.06725 1.99795 4.75698

>>> df['E'] = list('XYZ')
>>> df.astype(int, errors='ignore')
>>> print(df)
...     A   B   C   D   E
... 0   2   8   1   6   X
... 1   5   9   5   4   Y
... 2   0   4   1   4   Z
```

From [pandas.DataFrame.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) docs:

> errors : {‘raise’, ‘ignore’}, default ‘raise’
>
> Control raising of exceptions on invalid data for provided dtype.
>
> - raise : allow exceptions to be raised
> - **ignore : suppress exceptions. On error return original object**
>
> New in version 0.20.0.

Answer (score 12):

The columns that needs to be converted to int can be mentioned in a dictionary also as below

```
df = df.astype({'col1': 'int', 'col2': 'int', 'col3': 'int'})
```

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> right = pd.DataFrame({'C': [1.002, 2.003], 'D': [1.009, 4.55], 'key': ['K0', 'K1']})
>>> print(right)
           C      D key
    0  1.002  1.009  K0
    1  2.003  4.550  K1
>>> right['C'] = right.C.astype(int)
>>> print(right)
       C      D key
    0  1  1.009  K0
    1  2  4.550  K1
```

Answer (score 4):

In the text of the question is explained that the data comes from a csv. Só, I think that show options to make the conversion when the data is read and not after are relevant to the topic.

When importing spreadsheets or csv in a dataframe, "only integer columns" are commonly converted to float because excel stores all numerical values as floats and how the underlying libraries works.

When the file is read with [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) or [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) there are a couple of options avoid the after import conversion:

- parameter `dtype` allows a pass a dictionary of column names and target types like `dtype = {"my_column": "Int64"}`
- parameter `converters` can be used to pass a function that makes the conversion, for example changing NaN's with 0. `converters = {"my_column": lambda x: int(x) if x else 0}`
- parameter `convert_float` will convert "integral floats to int (i.e., 1.0 –> 1)", but take care with corner cases like NaN's. This parameter is only available in `read_excel`

To make the conversion in an existing dataframe several alternatives have been given in other comments, but since v1.0.0 pandas has a interesting function for this cases: [convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html), that "Convert columns to best possible dtypes using dtypes supporting pd.NA."

As example:

```py
In [3]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [4]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame( 
   ...:     { 
   ...:         "a": pd.Series([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.dtype("int64")), 
   ...:         "b": pd.Series([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=np.dtype("float")), 
   ...:         "c": pd.Series([1.0, np.nan, 3.0]), 
   ...:         "d": pd.Series([1, np.nan, 3]), 
   ...:     } 
   ...: )                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [6]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[6]: 
   a    b    c    d
0  1  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  2  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  3  3.0  3.0  3.0

In [7]: df.dtypes                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[7]: 
a      int64
b    float64
c    float64
d    float64
dtype: object

In [8]: converted = df.convert_dtypes()                                                                                                                                                                            

In [9]: converted.dtypes                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[9]: 
a    Int64
b    Int64
c    Int64
d    Int64
dtype: object

In [10]: converted                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[10]: 
   a  b     c     d
0  1  1     1     1
1  2  2  <NA>  <NA>
2  3  3     3     3
```

Comment: This is the answer people need to look at if they're using `pandas` >= 1.0. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many options here,
You can also convert the format of specific columns using a dictionary

```py
Data = pd.read_csv('Your_Data.csv')

Data_2 = Data.astype({"Column a":"int32", "Column_b": "float64", "Column_c": "int32"})

print(Data_2 .dtypes) # Check the dtypes of the columns
```

This is an useful and very fast way to change the data format of specific columns for quick data analysis.