# Convert a pandas data frame to a pandas data frame with another style

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

I have data frame containing the IDs of animals and types they belong to as given below

```
ID  Class
1   1
2   1
3   0
4   4
5   3
6   2
7   1
8   0
```

I want convert it to a new style with the classes on the header row as follows.

```
ID  0   1   2   3   4
1       1           
2       1           
3   1               
4                   1
5               1   
6           1       
7       1           
8   1
```

Can you help me to do it with python

Comment: See `get_dummies()`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`get_dummies()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
>>> print df

   ID  Class
0   1      1
1   2      1
2   3      0
3   4      4
4   5      3
5   6      2
6   7      1
7   8      0

>>> df2 = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Class'])
>>> print df2

   ID  Class_0  Class_1  Class_2  Class_3  Class_4
0   1        0        1        0        0        0
1   2        0        1        0        0        0
2   3        1        0        0        0        0
3   4        0        0        0        0        1
4   5        0        0        0        1        0
5   6        0        0        1        0        0
6   7        0        1        0        0        0
7   8        1        0        0        0        0
```

And if you want to get rid of "`Class_`" in the column headers, set both `prefix` and `prefix_sep` to the empty string:

`df2 = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Class'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get float values in the columns when I do it.  Can you help me with it?

Comment: They are `numpy.float64` for me too (though my displayed output doesn't show "`.0`"s, which is different from you for some reason). Do you just want to change the display, or do you want to change the underlying data type? Either way, I think you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas.