# How to prevent Pandas from converting my integers to floats when I merge two dataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({'AID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                       'D': [2011, 2011,0, 2011],
                       'R1': [0, 1, 0, 0],
                       'R2': [1, 0, 0, 0]  })

right = pd.DataFrame({'AID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                       'D': [2012, 0,0, 2012],
                       'R1': [0, 1, 0, 0],
                       'R2': [1, 0, 0, 0]  })

result = left.merge(right, how = 'outer')
```

When I print my result dataFrame, the integer values are now floats:

```
   AID       D   R1   R2
0  1.0  2011.0  0.0  1.0
1  2.0  2011.0  1.0  0.0
2  3.0     0.0  0.0  0.0
3  4.0  2011.0  0.0  0.0
4  1.0  2012.0  0.0  1.0
5  2.0     0.0  1.0  0.0
6  4.0  2012.0  0.0  0.0
```

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas

Comment: Apparently this is a bug and will be fixed in 0.18.2 https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8596

Comment: I can reproduce this problem and have voted to reopen. The code required to reproduce is slightly different

Comment: left = pd.DataFrame({'AID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                       'D': [2011, 2011,0, 2011],
                       'R1': [0, 1, 0, 0],

                    })

right = pd.DataFrame({'AID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                       'D': [2012, 0,0, 2012],
                       'R2': [1, 0, 0, 0]  
                     })


result = left.merge(right, how = 'outer', on=['AID', 'D'])

result

Comment: Be aware that floats can appear where one would only expect ints if a NaN value is produced as a result of a mismatch between the indexes or columns of the two dataframes. Be careful how you specify the type of merge, i.e. how you set the `how` kwarg in `.merge()`. This was the source of my problem. Lastly, I tried Rakesh's code but could not reproduce his/her error.

Answer (score 17):

This bug was fixed in pandas [v0.19.0.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.19.0.html#merging-changes):

> Merging will now preserve the dtype of the join keys

but note you can convert all columns in a dataframe to `int` dtype with:

```py
result = result.astype(int)
```

---

This behaviour [*does* still occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444480/how-to-prevent-pandas-from-converting-my-integers-to-floats-when-i-merge-two-dat/67004218#comment107882562_38444480) if there are unmatched records in the join, and hence `NaN`s in the results. In this case, you need to change the dtype to the [extension type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support) `'Int64'` to handle the `NaN`s:

```py
result = result.astype('Int64')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can cast the float back to an using

```
 result = left.merge(right, on='AID', how = 'outer')

 result['D_x']=result['D_x'].astype('Int64')
 result['R1_x']=result['R1_x'].astype('Int64')
 result['R2_x']=result['R2_x'].astype('Int64')
 result['D_y']=result['D_y'].astype('Int64')
 result['R1_y']=result['R1_y'].astype('Int64')
 result['R2_y']=result['R2_y'].astype('Int64')
```

if the data has null or missing data

```
import numbers
import math

left = pd.DataFrame({'AID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'D': [2011, 2011,0, 2011],
                   'R1': [0, 1, 0, 0],
                   'R2': [1, 0, 0, 0]  })

right = pd.DataFrame({'AID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'D': [2012, 0,0, 2012],
                   'R1': [0, 1, 0, 0],
                   'R2': [1, 0, 0, 0]  })

result = left.merge(right, how = 'outer')
result['AID']=[int(val) if isinstance(val,numbers.Number) & (math.isnan(val)==False) else 0 for val in result['AID']]
result['D']=[int(val) if isinstance(val,numbers.Number) & (math.isnan(val)==False) else 0 for val in result['D']]
result['R1']=[int(val) if isinstance(val,numbers.Number) & (math.isnan(val)==False) else 0 for val in result['R1']]
result['R2']=[int(val) if isinstance(val,numbers.Number) & (math.isnan(val)==False) else 0 for val in result['R2']]

 print(result)
 print(result.isna())
```

Output

```
AID     D  R1  R2
0    1  2011   0   1
1    2  2011   1   0
2    3     0   0   0
3    4  2011   0   0
4    1  2012   0   1
5    2     0   1   0
6    4  2012   0   0

   AID      D     R1     R2
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False
6  False  False  False  False
```

you can then replace the nan values with either: mean, 0, or interpolation value

Fixing Column D

```
def interpolate_list(y):
    idx = np.nonzero(y)
    x = np.arange(len(y))
    interp = interp1d(x[idx],y[idx])
   new_values = interp(x)
   return new_values

interp_d=interpolate_list(np.array(result['D']))
data=list(zip(interp_d,result['D']))
result['D']=[item[0] if item[1]==0 else item[1] for item in data]
print(result)
```

Output

```
   AID       D  R1  R2
0    1  2011.0   0   1
1    2  2011.0   1   0
2    3  2011.0   0   0
3    4  2011.0   0   0
4    1  2012.0   0   1
5    2  2012.0   1   0
6    4  2012.0   0   0
```

Comment: This works, unless there are unmatched records (as mentioned in the other response) with some fields containing `NaN`. In this case, you need `.astype('Int64')`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and this was because after the merge I got some NaN's values in the recasted column.

So, my "before" column was int32 and my "now" table is float64.

When I wanted to recast it to int32, I got this issue:

"ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"

So I just left it on float64 :D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately using `int64` as iacob suggests doesn't help me.
I used `type=object` and it worked perfectly. Mathematical operations are also possible when using this type.