# pandas merge() converts int into float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I found many people asking this on SO and some replied that this has been fixed a couple of years ago, but why I am still encounting this situation?

Here is the reproducing codes and results in ipython:

```
In [4]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'n': '001', 'b': 0}, {'n': '002', 'b': 1}])
In [5]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'n': '001', 'c': 3}])
In [6]: df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='n')
In [7]: df3
Out[7]: 
     n  b    c
0  001  0  3.0
1  002  1  NaN
In [8]: df2.dtypes
Out[8]: 
n    object
c     int64
dtype: object
In [9]: df3.dtypes
Out[9]: 
n     object
b      int64
c    float64
dtype: object
In [11]: pd.__version__
Out[11]: '1.3.0'
```

Comment: you need to convert `c` in `df2` to a pandas int; not the base numpy int : ``df2['c'] = df2.c.astype('Int64')``. That will keep the dtype as an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

casting after operation:

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'n': '001', 'b': 0}, {'n': '002', 'b': 1}])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'n': '001', 'c': 3}])
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='n')
    df3['b'] = df3['b'].astype(int)
    df3['c'] = df3['c'].astype(int)
    print(df3.dtypes)
```

---

more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67004218/9455902