# Convert floats to ints in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column ‘distance’ and it is of datatype ‘float64’.

```
Distance
14.827379
0.754254
0.2284546
1.833768
```

I want to convert these numbers to whole numbers (14,0,0,1). I tried with this but I get the error “ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer”.

```
df['distance(kmint)'] = result['Distance'].astype('int')
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: There are hacks to convert to int. But, the lack of NaN rep in integer columns is a pandas ["gotcha"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert floats to ints in Pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

I filtered out the NaN's from the dataframe using this:

```
result = result[np.isfinite(result['distance(km)'])]
```

Then, I was able to convert from float to int.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to convert the NaN values as part of your data import and cleaning processes. The more generalized solution could involve specifying the values that are NaN in the [read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) command by setting the na_values flag. What you want to make sure of is that there isn't some malfored data like 1.5km in one of your fields that getting picked up as a NaN value.

```
pandas.read_table(..., na_values=None, keep_default_na=True, na_filter=True, ....)
```

Subsequently, once the dataframe is populated and the NaN values are identified properly, you can use the [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method to substitute in zeros or the values that you identified as your distances. 
Finally, it would be best to probably use `notnull` versus `isfinite` to convert the over to integers.