# Remove decimal of columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
query   qstart  qend    name    number  strand
A       2.0     1064.0  None    0       +
B       2.0     1076.0  None    0       +
C       2.0     1064.0  None    0       +
D       0.0     741.0   None    0       +
```

and I would like to remove all decimals and get :

```
query   qstart  qend    name    number  strand
A       2       1064    None    0       +
B       2       1064    None    0       +
C       2       1064    None    0       +
D       0       741     None    0       +
```

I tried:

```
df['qstart']= round(df['qstart'])
df['qend']= round(df['qend'])
```

but it does not work...

Comment: [Hello, well this has already been answered here ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas/21291383#21291383)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the below:

```
m=(df.dtypes=='float')
df.loc[:,m]=df.loc[:,m].astype(int)
print(df)

  query  qstart  qend  name  number strand
0     A       2  1064  None       0      +
1     B       2  1076  None       0      +
2     C       2  1064  None       0      +
3     D       0   741  None       0      +
```

Comment: If you are dealing with missing (`np.nan`), a better alternative can be `astype('float64')`. Unless there is a specific purpose, for mathematic operations it will make no difference between 1064 and 1064.0

Answer (score 0):

```
df.qend = df.qend.apply(int) # round instead of int is you prefer to round
print (df)

  query  qstart  qend  name  number strand
0     A     2.0  1064  None       0      +
1     B     2.0  1076  None       0      +
2     C     2.0  1064  None       0      +
3     D     0.0   741  None       0      +
```

Comment: apply is not needed, `astype(int)` will do the job