# Python: How to convert whole array into int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to have an `int` matrix which has only its first column filled and the rest of elements are `Null`. Sorry but, I have a background of `R`. So, I know if I leave some `Null` elements it would be easier to manage them later. Meanwhile, if I leave `0` then it would be lots of problems later.

I have the following code:

```
   import numpy as np
   import numpy.random as random
   import pandas as pa

    def getRowData():
        rowDt = np.full((80,20), np.nan)
        rowDt[:,0] =  random.choice([1,2,3],80) # Set the first column
        return  rowDt
```

I wish that this function returns the `int`, but seems that it gives me `float`.

I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas), and tried the below code:

```
return  pa.to_numeric(rowDt)
```

But, it did not help me. Also the `rowDT` object does not have `.astype(<type>)`.

How can I convert an `int` array?

Comment: I think your code is wrong, shouldnt it be `np.random.choice` the choice function in the random module does not accept a second argument. Also, if rowDT has np.nan in it then it cannot be a integer array as np.nan cannot be represetned by integers. Would that explain it?

Comment: You could use `np.nan_to_num` but then you'd either use a different value for `full` in the first place, or you presumably need `nan` in which case the array cannot be of type `int`

Comment: numpy object do have `.astype(<type>)` function (version 1.14.3) and I was able to convert it to `int`, which version are you using?

Comment: @YilunZhang i am using `1.15.4`

Comment: A limitation of pandas: you cannot have `int` dtype with `null`, i.e. `nan`

Answer (score 1):

You create a full (`np.full` ) matrix of `np.nan`, which holds float `dtype`. This means you start off with a matrix defined to hold float numbers, not integers.

To fix this, fefine a full matrix with the integer `0` as initial value. That way, the `dtype` of your array is `np.int` and there is no need for `astype` or type casting.

```
rowDt = np.full((80,20), 0)
```

If you still wish to hold `np.nan` in your matrix, then I'm afraid you cannot use numpy arrays for that. You either hold *all* integers, or *all* floats.

Comment: i wish to have an `int` matrix wich has only its first column filled and the rest of elements are `Null` . Sorry, i have a background of `R`. So, i know if i make i have some `Null` elements it would be eaiser to manage them later. Meanwhile if i feel them with `0` then it would be lots of problem later.

Comment: @KamyarParastesh you can't have `null` and `int` in the same `numpy` array.

Comment: I mean, you *can*, but is highly not recommended. `np.array([np.nan, 1], dtype=object)` works, but you lose all the properties of a `np` array, and the use of numpy here gets weird.

Comment: Python doesn't have `null`.  `nan` is a float.  `None` is a unique object, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.ma.masked_array()` to create a [numpy masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html#index-0)

The numpy masked array "remembers" which elements are "masked". It provides methods and functions similar to those of numpy arrays, but excluding the masked values from the computations (such as, eg, `mean()`).

Once you have the masked array, you can always mask or unmask specific elements or rows or columns of elements whenever you want.