# Safely downcast a float to the smallest possible integer type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Pandas and numpy have a variety of ways to change numerical types but I couldn't find an automated way to safely convert a float to the smallest possible integer, given that no numerical info can be lost.

For example:

```
1.0 (float32)  ->  1 (int32)   # OK, 1 == 1.0
1.0 (float32)  ->  1 (int8)    # also OK, just more compact storage
1.4 (float32)  ->  1 (int8)    # not OK, 1 != 1.1
```

Here's some sample data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'i':[1.,333,555_666_777_888],
                  'j':[1.,333,555_666],
                  'x':np.random.randn(3) })
```

Looks like this (dtypes are all float64):

```
              i         j         x
0  1.000000e+00       1.0  0.852965
1  3.330000e+02     333.0 -0.955869
2  5.556668e+11  555666.0 -0.023493
```

Desired conversion

```
              i       j         x
0             1       1 -2.304234
1           333     333 -0.652469
2  555666777888  555666 -1.218302
```

with dtypes:

```
i      int64
j      int32
x    float64
```

I have a simple approach that I'll offer as an answer, but perhaps there are better ways or perhaps this is already part of pandas or numpy and I wasn't aware of it.

Also I'm punting on missing values in the answer (NaNs) as I don't have the latest version of of pandas (24.x) which allows integers to be NaN, so maybe someone would like to address that in an answer.

Note that there are few ways to convert floats to ints mentioned in this question:  [Convert floats to ints in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas/55753621#55753621), but none of them addresses the potential loss of numerical precision in converting something like 2.1 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function:

```
def float_to_int( s ):
    if ( s.astype(np.int64) == s ).all():
        return pd.to_numeric( s, downcast='integer' )
    else:
        return s

df.apply( float_to_int )
```

Output:

```
              i       j         x
0             1       1 -2.304234
1           333     333 -0.652469
2  555666777888  555666 -1.218302
```

With dtypes:

```
i      int64
j      int32
x    float64
```

Explanation:

I couldn't find an automated safe way to cast from float to integer, so I just check if converting a column to an integer changes the value.  If not, then I allow the casting from float to int.  Note that `int` defaults to `np.int32`, so using `np.int64` gives this a better chance of casting from float to int.

After that, pandas does all the work with `to_numeric()` as it will automatically convert to the smallest possible integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your answer, but you can set errors to 'ignore' and skip the check.

I use this:

```py
downcast_data = pd.to_numeric(data, downcast="unsigned", errors="ignore")
```

If it can't downcast, you just get the original back.