# Pandas : How can I change the type of the elements only in one column?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I created a pandas dataframe from mongo database using pymongo. In the database the elements in a column looks like integers but when I created the dataframe they are floats. I want them to be integers. How can I manage to do it? I just wanna change that column.

tried

```
X = X.astype({'x':'int'})
```

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://bla-bla")
mydb = myclient["p"]

mycol = mydb["aDB"]

colnames={ "_id": 1,"x":1, "y":1,"z":1}
X = pd.DataFrame(list(mycol.find({},colnames)))
```

Comment: Are you looking for `X['x'] = X['x'].astype(int)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert floats to ints in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
X['x'] = X['x'].astype('Int64')
```

Comment: The type of the elements in the column is <class 'numpy.float64'>. I get an error like : Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer