# How to convert all float columns in dataframe but except the first column?

Tags: python-3.x

I have searched but not found excatly what I need. I have a dataframe which has 50 columns. The first one is a date dtype, the rest are floats dtypes.

Now I want to convert ONLY the float columns into integer but NOT the date column. 
Can someone guide please?

When I slice the df like this `df_sub1=df_sub.iloc[:, 1:].apply(np.int64)` and then concat with the date column after, it crashes my laptop and did therefore not work. I hope there is a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert floats to ints in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas)

Answer (score 8):

Well assuming that date is your first column

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = df.columns
df[cols[1:]] = df[cols[1:]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: what does `errors='coerce'` do?

Comment: Sets invalid to NaN

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this.

```
new_df = df.drop(nameoffirstcolumn,1)
new_df.apply(np.int64)
```

then you can do something like.

```
final_df = pd.concat([df1['nameoffirstcolumn'],new_df], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the column name, the following code will do the work:

```
    import pandas as pd 

    # get all columns except the one with the date type
    cols = df.columns.difference(['date'])
    # convert the relevant columns
    df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float).astype(int)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).