# Handling object column with mixed data types by fixing floating point categories

Tags: python, pandas

[image: column with mixed dtype]

I have an object column with mixed data type and there are categories such as 57.0 and 57 that are being treated differently. Is it possible to convert the categories such as 57.0 to 57 so it is treated as same category without affecting the data type of the column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert floats to ints in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `int()` to the objects of type `float`;

```
df['category'] = df['category'].map(lambda x: int(x) if isinstance(x, float) else x)
```

`isinstance()` example:

```
>>> x = 12
>>> isinstance(x, int)
True
>>> y = 12.0
>>> isinstance(y, float)
True
```