# Convert dataframe float to int with all values in python

Tags: python

I have a data frame with 6 columns. I would like to convert one of the columns (the second one) from float to int, when I do this it only returns the one column as an int but I want the exact same dataframe in its entirety, the only difference is that the second column is int as opposed to float.

I have checked all relevant questions on here and nothing worked for me!! please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert floats to ints in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas)

Comment: The `astype` function in `pandas` might work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reassign to a new column or replace the same column values by

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].astype('int32')
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```py
>>> print(df)
  c1   c2  c3 c4  c5 c6
0  a  1.0   5  d  20  z
1  b  2.0   6  e  40  y
2  c  3.0   7  f  60  x
```

I believe you may be using [DataFrame.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to convert your column of floats to a column of ints. Specifically, it seems like you've gotten to this point:

```py
>>> df['c2'].astype(int)
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

Now, all you need to do is replace the column by calling:

```py
>>> df['c2'] = df['c2'].astype(int)
>>> print(df)
  c1  c2  c3 c4  c5 c6
0  a   1   5  d  20  z
1  b   2   6  e  40  y
2  c   3   7  f  60  x
```

---

If you'd like to create a new column of ints, you could do this instead:

```py
>>> df['new_col'] = df['c2'].astype(int)
>>> print(df)
  c1  c2    c3 c4  c5 c6  new_col
0  a   1.0   5  d  20  z        1
1  b   2.0   6  e  40  y        2
2  c   3.0   7  f  60  x        3
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's generally helpful to give some more detail as to what the code does.

Comment: You're right. I've updated the answer to include a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Much better answer. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this!

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                       'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                       'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                       index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

>>> df
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8

>>> df['test'] = df['num_wings'].astype('float')

>>> df
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen  test
falcon         2          2                 10   2.0
dog            4          0                  2   0.0
spider         8          0                  1   0.0
fish           0          0                  8   0.0
```

You can refer to this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) for more details!

Comment: Hey, could you please include the link's contents in your answer?

Comment: Here it is - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Comment: No, include the link's content(whatever the website says)in your answer. This is helpful in case the website changes, or the link rots.