# Trying to understand why iloc cannot be used to assign values to selected multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe with float values, I want to convert few columns as integers. I am trying to use iloc to select and assign values like below

Sample dataframe :

```
d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,4), columns = ["A","B","C","D"])

    A   B   C   D
0   0.610031    0.747877    0.781161    0.767779
1   0.029788    0.850722    0.472492    0.455788
2   0.647263    0.924750    0.965273    0.670915
3   0.393963    0.508282    0.700645    0.700494
4   0.166977    0.982876    0.859436    0.507221
```

Now all the columns generated here are floats and I want to convert column A and B to integers.

```
d.iloc[:,0:2] = d.iloc[:,0:2].astype(int)
```

The output is

```
    A   B   C   D
0   0.0 0.0 0.781161    0.767779
1   0.0 0.0 0.472492    0.455788
2   0.0 0.0 0.965273    0.670915
3   0.0 0.0 0.700645    0.700494
4   0.0 0.0 0.859436    0.507221
```

The values of column A and B have lost their numbers in decimal place as expected. However, they are still floats.

```
d.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   A       5 non-null      float64
 1   B       5 non-null      float64
 2   C       5 non-null      float64
 3   D       5 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 288.0 bytes
```

If I just print the output of `d.iloc[:,0:2].astype(int)`

output:

```
    A   B
0   0   0
1   0   0
2   0   0
3   0   0
4   0   0
```

I see the columns are converted to int. But when assigning back, they are converted back to float.
I am trying to understand what is happening here!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas Similar might help.

Comment: `d[['A', 'B']] = d.iloc[:,0:2].astype(int)` works. I'm not sure why `iloc` doesn't work. I can see the value changes, but the type does not.

Comment: My guess is that using .iloc or .loc allows for specifying by rows. When you use loc or iloc to assign a type, it is ensuring that the entire row is the same type, when updating the dataframe.