# How to preserve dtype int when reading integers with NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

The question might sound silly but I am interested to know the following:

```
my_df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_script.read(), engine).astype(object)
```

functions with the pandas version 1.0.5 and does not allow for the NaNs in the integer column to be turned to floats whereas on pandas version 1.3.5 `.astype(object)` does absolutely nothing.

I am curious to know why is this and of course what is the best approach for keeping the data obtained from sql as is without converting it to floats (where columns have NaNs because NaNs are floats).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want to keep the data obtained from SQL as is, then why are you using `.astype` at all?

Comment: The issue here is that where we have NaN in the columns where there are INTs it is converting them to floats. The INTs in those columns should not  be floats.

Comment: You mean, you have an integer column in your database that contains NULL entries, and because of that, pandas converts the column to float?  What do you want the value of those fields to be?

Comment: I want intigers to remain intigers without being converted to floats. I understand why they are being converted to floats but I am not sure what would be the best approach.

Comment: `pd.read_sql_query` is just a convenient shortcut, but it can't solve all problems.  If you need more control, feel free to query the database yourself and built the columns as you want, and THEN create a DataFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use dtype `'Int64'` for NaN support

- `'Int64'` (capital `I`) is a [pandas nullable integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70548802/13138364), so it can mix with NaNs.
- Default numpy integers cannot mix with NaNs, so the column will become dtype `object`.

---

For example, say column `Col D` contains only integers and NaNs:

- Either use the `dtype` param at load time (available in most `read_*` methods):

  ```
  df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_script.read(), engine, dtype={'Col D': 'Int64'})
  #                                                 ^^^^^
  ```
- Or use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) after loading:

  ```
  df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_script.read(), engine).astype({'Col D': 'Int64'})
  #                                                 ^^^^^^
  ```