# convert number from numpy.float64 to integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-2.7

I have the following dataframe:

```
     edad  id_tipo_propiedad
0     NaN                  2
1     NaN                  2
2     NaN                  2
3     NaN                  2
4     NaN                  2
5     NaN                  2
6  2011.0                  2
7     NaN                  2
8     NaN                  2
9     NaN                  2
```

The `edad` column is `numpy.float64` type. What I want to do is to convert all `numpy.float64` to integers, and to do that I'm using the following line of code:

```
df.edad.apply(lambda x: x if np.isnan(x) else int(x) if isinstance(x, (np.floating, float)) else x)
```

Basically, I'm trying to convert to integer if x is either a numpy float or just float. If x is `NaN` it should return x. Unfortunately, this solution is not working correctly since floats are not being converted to integers, they stay as numpy floats.

Note: I am using python2.7.

Comment: You can't do this without makeing the dtype of your column `object`, because `NaN` is a float and ints are converted to floats in the column if there are any floats in. Is that fine with you?

Comment: This should do the trick: `df.edad.fillna(0.0).astype(int)`. Fill Na first, then convert.

Comment: There is a nullable integer type in Pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html. So you can use `df.edad.astype('Int64')` (note capital "I"), but it will not be a `numpy` type.

Comment: More details on the nullable `Int64`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70548802/13138364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, it is not possible to convert from numpy.float64 to integer, first it is necessary to fill NaN values and then transform.

```
df['edad'] = df.edad.fillna(0)
df['edad'] = df.edad.atype(int)
```

or

```
df['edad'] = df.edad.fillna(0).astype(int)
```