# Pandas read_csv() converts integer columns to float if there are NaN. How does one keep them integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I need to use `read_csv()` to make a dataframe from a csv file. Most columns in the csv file are integer type (such as number of products bought) or string type (such as store name), but sometimes there might be float type (such as the weight of product in lbs).

I realize that Pandas convert the integer (int64) columns into float (float64) if there are blanks cells, which becomes NaN which is a float type.

I'd like to keep cells that originally had integers to stay integers. There are other parts of the program that relies on this.

I tried:

```
for col in data.columns:
    if data[col].dtype == np.float64:
        data[col] = data[col].astype(float).astype('Int64')
```

But this will try to change all float columns into integers. There are might columns that were originally float (as opposed to being coerced into float due to NaN) that I'd like to keep float.

I cannot specify a dictionary for dtype of each column when using `read_csv()` as each dataset is different and it'll be a lot of manual work.

I wonder if there is a way to treat all columns as "object" types when reading the csv? As I understand, "object" types allow for mixed types in columns.

Comment: "I wonder if there is a way to treat all columns as "object" types when reading the csv? As I understand, "object" types allow for mixed types in columns." That would be a really bad thing to do. You should just specify the dtype for integer columns as `pd.Int64Dtype()`, which is a special, nullable integer dtype by pandas.

Comment: "There are other parts of the program that relies on this." why?

Comment: To elaborate on "really bad thing to do"; you basically forfeit all optimisations you might get from numpy and vectorization if you make the columns 'object' type

Comment: [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) will convert to Int64 only when needed: `data = data.convert_dtypes()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot specify a dictionary for dtype of each column when using `read_csv()` as each dataset is different and it'll be a lot of manual work.

In this case, use [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) which will automatically assign `Int64` only when needed:

```
import io
csv = io.StringIO('''
foo,bar,baz
a,2.3,99
b,5.1,
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv).convert_dtypes()
#   foo  bar   baz
# 0   a  2.3    99
# 1   b  5.1  <NA>

df.dtypes
# foo     string
# bar    Float64
# baz      Int64
# dtype: object
```

Comment: Internally, how does Pandas represent `<NA>`? This is a little odd; I would expect that the dtype shows object if this is a `None` or float if it's a `NaN`.

Comment: @Reinderien The default `int64` (lowercase `i`) does use `np.NaN`, but `Int64` (uppercase `I`) uses the pandas-specific [`pd.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.NA.html#pandas.NA). This [`Int64Dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html) is an official [ExtensionDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#extensiondtype) that pandas maintains so they can support [nullable ints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70548802/13138364).